# "Riviera" or "Rivieras" for plural

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

I can't find a consensus in dictionaries on the accepted plural form of the word *Riviera*.

Is it *I'm going to see all of the Riviera of the world* or *I'm going to see all of the Rivieras of the world*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To distinguish a *[riviera](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Riviera)* from a *[Riviera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riviera)*, it should probably be lowercase:

> **1.** a resort area along the Mediterranean coast, extending from Saint Tropez, in SE France, to La Spezia, in NW Italy. See Côte d'Azur.
>   **2.** ( often lowercase ) any similar coastal resort area: *the Florida riviera.*

No less than four results come up when googling "[plural of riviera](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22plural%20of%20riviera%22)"; two are irrelevant. [This site](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/riviera.html) suggests *rivieras* as the plural form:

> The plural form of *riviera* is **rivieras**.

And the [other site](http://www.wordmagicsoft.com/dictionary/en-es/rivieras.php) does as well:

> **Rivieras** is the plural of **Riviera**

I would, in the absence of contradiction, follow English instinct and simply say *rivieras*, now that it's been naturalized to English.